# How do I reduce a curried function programatically?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, user-defined-functions

How can I reduce the function by currying it recursively 2 times? The 2 is a variable and tomorrow it can be three. I don't see any way to do this.  I have read through several post on stack overflow and none is doing this. This is basically a snippet of functional code which tries to generate a udf .

```
def lookupAndCreateColumn(allColNames:Seq[String])(column4:String)(column3:String)(column2:String)(column1:String):String = {

"somestring"
}
val allColNames= List("a","b")
var lookupCreateColCurried = lookupAndCreateColumn(allColNames.toList) _



def callFuncRecursively(func:Any,callMax:Int,curryArg:String) = {
    def callFunc(func:Any,callMax:Int,curryArg:String,incr:Int):Object = {
        if(incr==callMax) func else {
           val p = incr + 1
           callFunc(func(curryArg),callMax,curryArg,p)
        }
    }
    callFunc(func,callMax,curryArg,0)
}

callFuncRecursively(lookupCreateColCurried,2,"not_defined")
```

Comment: Every recursive iteration changes the `func` type so you wouldn't have any type safety. Not a good idea. Why not just put all the `columnX` data in a collection and, when you have enough, call the func directly?

Comment: Looks like XY-problem. What was the original goal that you tried to achieve with this tower of curried functions?

Comment: I agree with @AndreyTyukin. I have a feeling, that whatever you want to achieve, you would sooner implement with shapeless and type-class derivation - there you would be able to recursively build a function, that would do what you actually want.